# Cookie problem - Login backend

Tags: multistore, ce-1.9.1.0, login, backend, cookie

I have two Magento websites in the same domain, **store.com** and **us.store.com**.

For 24 hours I can't login in the backend. Only If I use a plugin browser like anonimoX, which changes my IP the login works. So I think it is a problem witht cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in `System > Configuration > Web > Session Cookie Management` and set a different cookie domain for your two websites.

- First website: `store.com` (make sure it is NOT `.store.com`)
- Second website: `us.store.com`

**Flush your cache** (both **Magento** and **browser**) and try again, it should fix it.

Comment: se il mio sito è store.com e us.store.com e nel primo metto come cookie domain ciao.com e nell'altro saluti.com che sono due altri miei domini? è possibile?

Comment: Io intendevo il primo su "us.store.com" e il secondo "store.com". Tecnicamente dovrebbero risultare domini differenti se non usi il "." davanti al nome come wildcard. P.S: Prova anche aumentando il cookie lifetime, spesso 3600 sono troppo pochi se c'è un problema di orari.

Comment: allora nel dominio di terzo livello il login al backend funziona, non ancora però sullo store principale, si il timing è 84600 ora, ci sono altri metodi?

Comment: ho notato però che nel nome dell'host risulta il punto davanti al nome del sito (ho controllato con webdeveloper tool la pagina)

Comment: Togli il punto davanti perché è un wildcard, ti si sovrappone con l'altro.

Comment: Ottimo risolto, grazie riccardo.